# Error PDO class not found in PHP 7.4 Alpine 3.11

Tags: php, docker, pdo, alpine-linux

I am using docker-php-ext-* library to install several packages needed in my web app.
I based on the official docker image instruction they provided on the home page on Docker hub but got the error below, and appreciate your help.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-alpine3.11

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --update bash zlib zlib-dev apache2 curl ca-certificates openssl openssh tzdata openntpd nano \
    php7-apache2 php7-phar php7-json php7-iconv php7-openssl

RUN docker-php-source extract
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-enable gd pdo pdo_mysql mysqli
RUN docker-php-source delete

# setup project
# prapre /opt/entrypoint.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash" , "/opt/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 80
```

/opt/entrypoint.sh content `httpd -D FOREGROUND`

Error
php -m showing all packages i installed successfully (gd pdo pdo_mysql mysqli), 
but when i try

`<?php new PDO(.....);?>`

I got

`PDO class not found`

Same question on the github repo for the docker-php-ext library https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/986.

Any hint will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Just a quick check, can you try `new \PDO` to see if it's a namespace problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, will try your suggestion and get back to you soon.

Comment: @NigelRen I checked RB.php file (BTW, RedBeanphp is the micro-ORM I am using right now in my app) and found that this Library is using already your suggested way new \PDO. your thoughts?